# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n}\log\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: calculus

Please help me to solve this problem. I can find almost no clue regarding the log part. I tried to break the $\binom{2n}{n}$ part, but in vague...will the breaking help me in anyway?

Comment: Think about a Riemann sum

Comment: Are you sure it's that? Something tells me it's the limit of $\frac{\binom {2n}{n}}{2n}.$

Comment: $\binom{2n}{n}$  doesn't matter. As long as it is an integer $\ge 2$, $\frac{1}{2n\log\binom{2n}{n}} \le \frac{1}{2\log(2) n}$...

Comment: Hmm... looking at the edit revisions. the edit from version 1 to version 2 seems wrong. The very original question can be interpreted as finding the limit of $\frac{1}{2n}\log\binom{2n}{n}$ too.

Comment: I meant $\frac{\log \binom {2n}{n}}{2n}.$

Comment: all - I changed the question to what it supposed to ask (based on edit version 1)

Comment: I think like @zhw it should be $\frac{\log{\binom{2n}{n}}}{2n}$ otherwise the limit is $0$ like in the hints I the answer of Elaqqad

Comment: It would be nice if MATHS would join in and reveal which question is being asked rather than those speculations!

Answer (score 5):

$$\log\binom{2n}{n}=\log\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n+k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\frac{1+\frac{k}{n}}{\frac{k}{n}}\approx n\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)\,dx = 2n\log 2.$$

Answer (score 2):

There are $2^{2n}=4^n$ subsets of a set of size $2n$, each of which has between $0$ and $2n$ elements.  Of these, ${2n}\choose{n}$ have exactly $n$ elements, and ${{2n}\choose{n}} > {{2n}\choose{k}}$ for any $k\neq n$.  Therefore,
$$
\frac{4^n}{2n+1} < {{2n}\choose{n}} \le 4^n,
$$
so
$$
n\log 4-\log(2n+1) < \log{{2n}\choose{n}} \le n \log 4,
$$
and
$$
\log 2-\frac{\log(2n+1)}{2n} < \frac{1}{2n}\log{{2n}\choose{n}} \le \log 2.
$$
We conclude that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2n}\log{{2n}\choose{n}} = \log 2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** You can use the following inequality: $$\frac{4^n}{n}\leq{2n \choose n}\leq 4^n$$ for large $n\geq 4$ ([this is the proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate#Proof_by_Shigenori_Tochiori) for the left inequality)